# Add a "very preliminary" mention in the title page

Tags: titles

Is there an efficient way to add a mention such as "very preliminary" in the title page of a paper? My attempt was to add it in the `\date{}` command but this looks more like a trick than something else.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\begin{document}
\title{Analysis\thanks{The author thanks http://tex.stackexchange.com/ for its valuable help.}}
\author{Me\thanks{Here}}
\date{Very Preliminary \\ \today}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract} 
Yes.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: An often used trick ;-) Alternatively you can use conditionals to display the `preliminary` or not or the `background` package which shows `Draft` by default as a kind of watermark

Comment: Some tricks are just good. I mean, why no? if this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks. But I am surprised that this cheap trick is so often used given that everything is customized here. I expected something more fancy ;-)!
In my example the line space between the mention "very preliminary" and the date is very small. Is there a "trick" to increase it?

Comment: By "fancy" do you mean some like  `\subtitle{Very premilinar}` ? There  is not that  command in  `article` , but  you can do that in  `paper` (for example) or `\titlehead{...}` in a KOMA book, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very minimal package `preliminary.sty` which will add the notation if `draft` is active, but not otherwise. It depends on `titling.sty`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{preliminary.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{preliminary}
\DeclareOption{draft}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand\maketitlehookc{%
      \begin{center}Very Preliminary\end{center}}}}
\ProcessOptions
\RequirePackage{titling}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage{preliminary}
\begin{document}
  \title{Analysis\thanks{The author thanks http://tex.stackexchange.com/ for its valuable help.}}
\author{Me\thanks{Here}}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Yes.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image: preliminary version]

Removing `draft` from the options passed to `article`:

[image: final version]

Comment: @emeryville Thanks. I like `titling`'s hooks. Make it so easy to customise the title!