# How can I put "preliminary" below the date?

Tags: titles

I would like to add "preliminary" to my document. I tried the accepted answer in this one:
[Add a "very preliminary" mention in the title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277990/add-a-very-preliminary-mention-in-the-title-page)
But I would like to put it below the date. How can I achieve this? (BTW, what is its conventional location?)

Thank you very much!

```
\begin{filecontents}{preliminary.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{preliminary}
\DeclareOption{draft}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand\maketitlehookc{%
      \begin{center} \Large \textbf{ \color{red}{Preliminary}}\end{center}}}}
\ProcessOptions
\RequirePackage{titling}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt, draft]{article}
\usepackage{preliminary}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl, amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=red,
urlcolor=red,
linktoc=all,
citecolor=blue
       }
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[letterpaper, width=17cm, height=20cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}



\definecolor{mygray1}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{mygray2}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{mygray3}{gray}{0.4}
\definecolor{mygray4}{gray}{0.2}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{claim}{{\sc Claim}}
\newtheorem{condition}{Condition}

\newcommand{\tc}{\textcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek}



\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,intersections,through,backgrounds} 
\usepackage[capposition=bottom]{floatrow}

\newcommand{\argmax}{arg\max}
\newcommand{\argmin}{arg\min}
\newcommand*{\QEDA}{\null\nobreak\hfill\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}%


\begin{document}

\title{XX, XX, and XX: \\ How YY May YY YY}

\author{ZZ}


\affil{University of Ohh}

%\date{\today}
%\date{}
\date{\today}





\maketitle




\begin{abstract}
ABC


\noindent {\bf Keywords}: AAA
\end{abstract}



\end{document}
```

Among them, the key is the following part:

```
\begin{filecontents}{preliminary.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{preliminary}
\DeclareOption{draft}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand\maketitlehookc{%
      \begin{center} \Large \textbf{ \color{red}{Preliminary}}\end{center}}}}
\ProcessOptions
\RequirePackage{titling}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt, draft]{article}
\usepackage{preliminary}
```

[image]

Comment: Your example does not compile without error

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sorry, now it should work.

Comment: @Ypbor Please consider accepting and upvoting the provided answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [`titling` package](//ctan.org/pkg/titling) provides a number of hooks: `\maketitlehookc` fits between the `\affil`liation and the `\date`, while `\maketitlehookd` follows the `\date`. So change your `preliminary.sty` to update `\maketitlehookd` instead of `\miketitlehookc`:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{preliminary.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{preliminary}
\DeclareOption{draft}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand\maketitlehookd{%
      \begin{center}
        \Large\bfseries\color{red}%
        Preliminary
      \end{center}}}}
\ProcessOptions
\RequirePackage{titling}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! BTW, do you know whether we should put it above or below the date according to academic tradition?

Comment: @Ypbor: I don't know of any "academic tradition." Ask your school/university.